# How to add new item to .net-core project in macOS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new in .net core.
I created my new empty project with this command :

```
dotnet new web -n MyTestApp
```

if it is right?
Then i added a new folder called Controllers, and now i want to add new

> HomeController.cs

to this folder, i want to know how?
In Visual Studio simply i right click on Controllers folder and add new item to this folder, but in Visual Studio Code as you know we don't have New Item menu.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to your project directory.
In net core you don't need to list each project file in your csproj or project.json.